# AJAX load page and reload/add after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

So I have a page which, when requested, updates my database. For example when I go to `database_update.php` it just updates the database and doesn't show anything.

`Index.php` shows user database content.

So I have function in JavaScript called `update` which must use AJAX to run this page and after the page loads (after all queries run successfully) it must load `index.php` and show updated page to the user (reload the page without refresh effect).

My code is like:

```
$.get('ajax_update_table.php', {
    // The following is important because page saves to another table
    // users nick which call update:
    update: UserLogin
}, function (output) {
    // The following is unimportant:
    $(myDiv).html(output).show();
});
```

Comment: What is your question, specifically?

Comment: I am also unsure of what, specifically, you are trying to do.  You are making an ajax call that, when complete, you want to update some content on the page *without* reloading the entire page?

Comment: hmm, in steps:
#1 go to index.php
#2 click on link which calls function update_database
#3 run code in update_database.php (call it with ajax)
#4 when update is complete (page loads in 100%) load index.php with ajax
#5 change content on pege (step #1, index.php) with new values from ajax (new version of index.php) BUT without visible page refresh (more like append in JS but delete old data and present only new)

Hope it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Return a "success" or "error" code from your database_update script.  Returning a JSON string is very easy. For example:

   ```
   echo '{"success":"success"}';
   ```
2. Use the $.ajax function.  Then add the success, error, and complete parameters.  You can call any javascript function(s) when the AJAX request is complete.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: 'update_database.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {successFunction(data)},
       error: function () { error(); },
       complete: function () { complete(); }
   });

   function successFunction(data) {
       if ('success' in data) {
           // Do success stuff here.
       } else {
           // Show errors here
       }
   }
   // .... etc
   ```

Comment: Sorry the code formatting isn't working.... ??? not happy with the StackOverflow markup language.

Comment: ok, but how to load entire page (index.php) in
> if ('success' in data) 
and next append it to actual page (which is also index.php)

Comment: Why not just "refresh" the page? if you have set your session/cookie values appropriately, the next time the index page loads, it can show the new information.  You can refresh by using the javascript  document.location.reload(true); function. (true causes it to reload from server, not cache)

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I'll try to answer your question.

I would setup a blank page that on loading it sends the index.php to a div on that page. For example, make a page titled blank.php.

blank.php would have the following:

```
function Index(){
$.ajax({
    url:"index.php",
    type: "GET",
    success:function(result){
        $("#web-content").html(result);
    }
});
}

<script type="text/javascript">Index();</script>
<div id="web-content"></div>
```

You would then have your index execute the Index function to update the web-content div with the index.php data without reloading the blank.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" SRC="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    function update_and_replace()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_update_table.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {successFunction(data)},
                error: function () { error(); },
                complete: function () { complete(); }
            });
        }

        function successFunction(data) {
            if ('success' in data) {
                $("#content").load("index.php");
            } 
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
Now is: <?php echo date("Y-m-d, H:i:s");?>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="update_and_replace();">Aktualizuj</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax_update_table.php

```
<?php echo '{"success":"success"}'; ?>
```

Thank You all for your help.
I know that my English is bad but with your help I made it!